# How to find out which Columns are nullable in a DataTable?

Tags: datatable, dbnull, datacolumn

Is there a way to find out which columns are nullable in a DataTable?
I know that there is a proprety: DataColumn.AllowDBNull, which can be set to true or false in the design mode of the DataSet, but I would like to have this information directly from the database.

I am having a DGV populated with values from a MySQL database and have bound the DataSource of the DGV to a DataTable.

Comment: Do you want to query a DataTable for nullable columns or the database directly?

Comment: I want to query the DataTable, if possible. I am entering new data in the DataTable while it is offline. Is there a way for the DataTable to store the information of nullable and not nullable columns?

Answer (score 1):

As a solution I decided to retrieve the Columns Schema of the Database and from there assign which Collumns AllowDBNull:

```
     DataTable dbColumnsSchema;
     using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
        dbColumnsSchema = connection.GetSchema("Columns");
            connection.Close();

        }

        AssignMandatoryColumns(dbColumnsSchema);

    }

    private void AssignMandatoryColumns(DataTable table)
    {
      foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            if (row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()==myTableName)
                if(row["IS_NULLABLE"].ToString()=="NO")
                {  string columnName = row["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
                    myDataSet.Tables[myTableName].Columns[columnName].
                        AllowDBNull = false;
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to determine which DataColumns in a DataTable are nullable (have [`AllowDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull.aspx) set to true):

```
var nullableDataColumns = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.AllowDBNull);
foreach (var col in nullableDataColumns) {
    Console.WriteLine(col.ColumnName);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately by default all  the DataColumn.AllowDBNull are set to true, unless you change yourself the values in the DataSet design mode.